# Tastypie write-only field?

Tags: django, tastypie

Suppose you upload files first
then create a post to hold the files.

1. a user upload a file
2. he gets a `id` of the file
3. he writes up other parts before finally saving(creating) a post.
4. he sends the id (of the file) to the server along with other data.
5. server retrieves the image using the id and save the image in the imagefield of the Post model.

Here, the `id` of the file is write-only field, ie, you only need it when you create the model instance.

How do you handle that in tastypie?

Answer (score 0):

Using Tastypie you can use [excludes](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#excludes)

```
class Meta:
    excludes = ['file_field_name']
```

This will not display actual field in GET request. To avoid the re-write operation on this field than tastypie gives you method [obj_update](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#obj-update) which gets executes only on PUT and PATCH request So you need to override this method in your ModelResource class where you can ommit the `file_field` to update. Such as

```
def obj_update(self, bundle, request, **kwargs):
    bundle.data.pop('file_field')
    return super(ModelResource_class, self).obj_update(bundle, bundle.request, **kwargs)
```

Let me know if this can help you.
Thanks.